# Resting a site for a couple of years

Tags: hosting

I have an old website. I plan on not publishing it for a couple of years. I’ll need it in the future, but I don’t need it now. Therefore, I don’t need to pay for the hosting.  I’m a complete beginner. Can you let me know how I can save the content somewhere and switch off the hosting, but keep my content safely? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a myriad of plugins out there, or do it manually.

Plugin:
Almost never used one, from the looks of it, this should do the job: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ - you can also search for other plugins that "migrate".

Make sure that the exported *.zip (or other format) file contains the database, the code and other resources like uploads. Best would be to use this dump to re-install locally.

Manually:
In order to replicate a wordpress website you would need the following:

1. Database
2. Code
3. Other resources like uploads

The code+resources is stores on the hosting, probably FTP, SFTP. You probably have also a local copy of the code, but not nessesary the resources, so try to just download it all. If you have Staging and Production, make sure to backup each separately.

The database is probably hosted by your hosting service, but stored on a separate server, if you have access to cPanel you can search for phpmyadmin. This is a graphic interface to work with your database. There you can export the database in *.sql form.

If you cannot find a way to export the database, ask your hosting provider. If you have Staging and Production, ask them for DB dump of both.

Note:
The database contains direct link to the hosting domain. Use tools like search-replace, wp cli search-replace or interconnectit

Answer (score 0):

Relying on a plugin to take the backup would be a bad idea. You'll never know if that plugin will be there in 2 years. Go for a manual backup.

1. Take the MySQL database backup from phpMyAdmin. Every cPanel has option to access it from there.
2. Take the files backup from FTP (Or you can compress the whole installation folder from File Manager in cPanel).

You are done.

A quick note. A lot will change in 2 years so do WordPress. When you reinstall/restore everything after 2 years, you will be prompted to update WordPress and Plugins. I'd recommend updating WordPress first, that too manually step by step for major releases.